# Tree-like data structure in c++ optimal for compact storage only

Tags: c++, memory-management, tree

There are tons of questions about tree-like data structures, also in c++.

Here is a very specific one that I need: I have to store data consisting of assignments of natural numbers to finite sequences of natural numbers. So, a typical entry would be something like `(5,11,6,2,4,8,8,3,1) -> 788569`. My only priority is to store these as compactly as possible. So I would like to have a program which does the following: it looks up `x=f(5)`, then `y=x(11)`, then `z=y(6)`, then `t=z(2)`, then `u=t(4)` then `v=u(8)`, then `w=v(8)`, then `s=w(3)` then `r=s(1)`; if `r(0)` is defined, it must return `788569`; if it is undefined, another program should then compute this value according to an algorithm supplied by me, make `r(0)` defined and equal to this particular value.

Similarly if on any intermediate stage the result was undefined - say, `u(8)` was undefined - the program should extend the corresponding branch with `v=u(8)`, `s=v(3)`, `r=s(1)` and `r(0)=788569` (again computing the latter value according to the algorithm supplied by me).

Unfortunately I cannot estimate how many such sequences up to given length will occur in my computations; definitely not all, but I do not know the proportion. Eventually I will probably need to erase some of the data to prevent memory overflow; to keep it simple, let us assume I will just chop off least visited branches.

So is there any ready-made structure in c++ for such kind of storage?

Comment: @ArminMontigny You mean something like recursively defined unordered map of unordered maps? Because I would need expressions like `m[5][11][6][2][4]`, etc., into arbitrary depth

Comment: more like `unordered_map<std::array<int, 9>, int>` for the result. The bigger question is how to store `x, y, z, t, u, v, w, s, r`. as each of those has a different key length and value type.

Comment: Do you actually have arbitrary depth and each sequence of function is terminated when the input sequence stops and you call `f(0)` on the last generated function?

Comment: What is your algorithm for generating `x, y, z, z, u, v, w, s, r` and what is their type?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I am computing certain function `F(n)`; each `F(n)` is actually `F(n,{})` and requires various intermediate values of the form `F(m,{a1,...,ak})` for `a1+...+ak<m` which I want to store in cache. Each `x, y, z, ...` represents a branch in the tree whose leaves are those values `F(m,{a1,...,ak})`

Comment: And what type is that? Because in your question you have: `int r(int)`, `int (*s)(int)(int)`, `int (*w)(int)(int)(int)`, ... You could change it to have objects with `std::variant<int, std::pair<FunctionObj, std::vector<args>> operator()(std::vector<args>);` or something so they all have the same type.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Let me try this way. I need a type `T` such that for any `m` of type `T`, every time I invoke, say, `m[5][11][43][2][2]`, this would have certain value which is an arbitrary size nonnegative integer; if that value is `0` I should be able to assign to it (according to an algorithm that I have in place) another (positive) value. That's it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the main thing: **only** those values that I encounter in computations should take up memory. When I say `0` this in fact means that the corresponding expression was unevaluated and did not take up any memory before I invoked it, as `map`-like structures do. In particular, when I evaluate, say, `m[5][11][43]`, this should not require allocating any memory for `m[5][11][42]` or say for `m[5][11][30]`

Comment: That isn't even the question. Your `m[5][11][43][2][2]` is `f(5)(11)(43)(2)(2)(0)` where each of those intermediate functions is generated by you and needs to be stored. And you won't tell the type or show the code that generates them. So lacking any information about the type the only possible way to store it would be `std::unordered_map<std::vector<int>, std::any>`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow But the question is precisely about this! How to store **only** the values I encounter without building any redundant data structures that would take up memory. For example, I need `m[5][11]` but do not want to allocate anything for `m[4]`, `m[5][1]`, `m[5][2]`, `m[5][3]`, etc. unless it turns out *later* that I need them too, in which case I should be able to allocate memory for them later, *if needed*.

Comment: Any map will already do that, if you can define a type for it.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I don't know how to define a type for it, this is my question. Could you provide an answer?

Comment: Let T be the type your function generator returns then use `std::map<int, T>`. Why do you think I keep asking you what your function generator has as type?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Sorry but I don't understand what function generator means. I will assign positive integers to a bunch of sequences of integers. I want to store these values. I want to do it in such way that the sequence `(4,1,8,8,5,2)` with value `51332` and the sequence `(4,1,8,8,5,2,9)` with value `4385` are not stored separately. Rather I want to have a tree with one of the branches `4->1->8->8->5->2->9->...` and the value `51332` attached to a leaf at `...->2->...` while the value `4385` attached to a leaf at `...->9->...`

Comment: Now you are describing something completely different. Where did all that talk about functions x, y, z, t, u, v, r go? So you want to create a tree for all your sequences and store a value in each node. Just do it. Only think simpler than a tree is a list.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow In each case I tried to explain one and the same thing. When one way failed I tried another. Not sure this time I did not fail again. I think a list would not suffice since there are many branches. Along with `4->1->8->8->5->...` I might have `4->1->8->2->5->2->...`, `4->1->8->2->1->11->...`, `4->1->8->7->43->12->...` and so on

Comment: I didn't say you should use a list. Only that a tree is just one step above that. You don't need any fancy structure for what you ask. So just go ahead and implement a tree structure and if you you get stuck then ask another question showing what you have tried.